# How does Eisenstein's criterion use primeness?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

I'm not sure I understand this proof in Dummit-Foote.

When we reduce modulo $P$, we get $x^n=\overline{a(x)b(x)}=\overline{a(x)}\cdot\overline {b(x)}$. Let $$a(x)=x^k+\dots+a'_0\\b(x)=x^l+\dots+b_0$$

They claim $\overline a'_0=\overline b_0=\overline 0$
 (or $a'_0,b_0\in P$). My explanation is this: $x^n$ divides the residues of $a(x)$ and $b(x)$ in $R/I[x]$. So $\overline a(x)=x^k, \overline b(x)=x^l$. Thus $a'_0,b_0\in P$. Is this a correct reasoning? But then the proof does not use that $P$ is prime. Or if it does use it, then how?

> [image]

Also, I took a look at the proof in Artin (he only proves for $\mathbb Z$), and I also don't see how he uses that $p$ is a prime number! For reference, here is Artin's proof:

> [image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Artin's proof, the primality of $p$ is used in the step:

> $\overline{g}$ divides $\overline{a_n}x^n$, so $\overline{g}$ has the form $\overline{b_r}x^r$.

This step uses the fact that $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ is a field, so that $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}[x]$ is a unique factorization domain, which allows us to draw the above conclusion.

Comment: I see. So can I apply the same argument in the Dummit-Foote setting to conclude that $\overline{a(x)}=x^k$ and  $\overline{a(x)}=x^l$ in $(R/I)[x]$? And in such a case, that's where the fact that the ideal $P$ is prime used?

Comment: In the general case, it's not so simple, because  you only know that $R/P$ is an integral domain, not necessarily a field, so you can't invoke unique factorization.  You have to work harder - In fact, I don't quite follow the argument given by Dummit and Foote (particularly, the part that says "it follows that both $\overline{a(x)}$ and $\overline{b(x)}$ has 0 constant term").

Comment: I would argue this way: we know that $a_0 b_0 \in P$, hence WLOG assume $a_0 \in P$.  Let $i$ be the smallest index such that $a_i \not \in P$. If $i<n$ (where $n$ is the degree of $a(x)$), then $a_i b_0 + a_{i-1} b_1 + \ldots + a_0 b_i \in P$. All terms besides $a_i b_0$ are in $P$ by minimality of $i$.  Hence $a_i b_0 \in P$ too, and since $a_i \not \in P$, we conclude that $b_0 \in P$.  Contradiction since this means $a_0 b_0 \in P^2$.  Therefore $i=n$ and hence $a(x)$ reduces mod $P$ to a power of $x$, hence so does $b(x)$ (for this we only need that $(R/P)[x]$ is a domain), contradiction.

Comment: Why is $a_0b_0\in P^2$ a contradiction? I would say if $b_0\in P$, then we are done. Otherwise (if $a_i\in P$), we get a contradiction. And how do we use that $R/P[x]$ is a domain?

Comment: $a_0 b_0 \in P^2$ is a contradiction because $a_0 b_0$ is the constant term of the original polynomial, and we're assuming that the constant term is not in $P^2$.  We don't really need the fact that $R/P[x]$ is a domain explicitly (this is implicit in the fact that $P$ is prime). I thought we needed it after concluding that $a(x)$ is a power of $x$ (mod $P$), in order to conclude that $b(x)$ is also a power of $x$ by cancellation. But this case is simple enough that you can just write out the coefficients without invoking the fact that $R/P$ is a domain.

Comment: @Ted what is$ P^2$

Comment: @CloudJR It's the square of the ideal $P$.  In general, the product of two ideals $I$ and $J$ is defined as the set of all elements of the form $\sum_{i=1}^n x_i y_i$ where $x_i \in I, y_i \in J$.  See https://commalg.subwiki.org/wiki/Product_of_ideals for more details.